# Pure javascript validation

Tags: javascript

I am tiring to do valid email and required fields validation but with this function i do witch i want to do with only pure JavaScript it keep show only the required em

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>JS valdation</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            var email = document.getElementById('emailaddress');
            var name = document.getElementById('username');
            var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            if (email.value == "" || name.value == "") {
                document.getElementById("required").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("required_email").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("valide_email").style.display = "none";
            }
            else if(!filter.test(email.value)) {
                document.getElementById("valide_email").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("required").style.display = "none";
            }
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
Email: <input id="emailaddress" type="text" name="email">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<em id="valide_email" style="display:none">please enter a valid email ex:(user@user.com)</em>
<em id="required_email" style="display:none">this filed is required</em>
First name: <input id="username" type="text" name="fname">
<em id="required" style="display:none">this filed is required</em>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i want to show the valide_email em when email is valid

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html , just don't.

Answer (score 0):

In your Css  style sheet add these two classes(or as Id's)

```
#valide_email.visible, #required_email.visible {
    visibility:hidden; /*or display: none or whatever*/
}
#valide_email.hidden, #required_email.hidden {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

In your javascript you can change their class between hidden and visible like this:

```
else if(!filter.test(email.value)) {
     document.getElementById("valide_email").className = "visible";
     document.getElementById("required").className = "hidden";
}
```